# Как сделать задний фон правильно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

Смотрите, у меня есть сайт, на нем есть много div-ов, я хочу все эти div-ы поместить в один контейнер и задать этому контейнеру цвет. Но при этих действиях задний фон укорачивается и делается короче.
Примерно вот-так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внимание вопрос! Как мне сделать этот задний фон длиннее по вертикали?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("show-moddal");
const modal = document.getElementById("modal1");

const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".modal_close");

btn.onclick = () => 
{
    modal.classList.add("modal_active");

    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
    modal.addEventListener("click", hideModal);

    function closeModal() 
    {
      modal.classList.remove("modal_active");
      closeBtn.removeEventListener("click", closeModal);
      modal.removeEventListener("click", hideModal);
    }

    function hideModal(event) 
    {
      if (event.target === modal) 
      {
          closeModal();
      }
    }
};
```

```css
body 
{
    line-height: 1.5;    
    background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}

.page 
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 1870px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.header 
{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;

    
}

.title 
{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub_title 
{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav 
{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;

}

.link 
{
    padding: 8px 12px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

main 
{
    display: block;
    
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}



.content 
{
    width: 1870px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    
    
}

.image 
{
    margin-left: 435px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;

    
}

.content-title 
{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 435px;

    color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.content-title2 
{
    margin: 0px;
    

    color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.link:hover 
{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


.article 
{
    margin:0;
    margin-left: 435px;
    width: 1000px;
    
    padding-bottom: 20px;

    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(26, 25, 46);
    

    padding-top: 20px;
    

    
    
    
    
}


.article-title 
{
    margin:0;
    
    color: rgb(31, 25, 95);
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.time 
{
    
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.article-text 
{
    

    font-weight: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.read_all
{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer 
{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
    
}

.uvideo 
{
   height: 350px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.uvideo-content 
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.uvideo-content_text 
{
    font-size: 19px;
    
    padding:25px;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    
}

.yoytube 
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.memeil 
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
    
    
    
}

.data_site 
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}



.modal 
{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal_content 
{
    background-color: white;
    width:80%;
    padding: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
    margin: 15px auto 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);


    position: relative;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;

}

.modal_close 
{
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    float: right;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.modal_active 
{
    display:block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal_close:hover, 
.modal_close:focus 
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.article-title_modal 
{
    color: rgb(31, 25, 95);
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.image-modal 
{
  width: 200px;
}


.author
{
    display:flex;
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    
}

.avatar 
{
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.News 
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Простая страница</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />      
  </head>

  <body>

    
   
     <div class = "page" id = "part1">
        <div class = "header">
        
         <h1 class = "title">Мой первый сайт</h1>
         <h2 class = "sub_title">Добро пожаловать</h2>
        </div>

        <div class = "nav">

         <a class = "link" href = "#part1">Главная</a>
         <a class = "link" href = "#part2">Новости</a>
         <a class = "link" href = "#part3">Видео</a>
         <a class = "link" href = "#part4">Об авторе</a>

        </div>
        <div class = "container">
          <main class = "content">

            

           <img src = "1000px-Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2.jpg" class = "image">

           
           <h3 class = "content-title" id = "part2">Новости</h3>
          


           <article class = "article">

            <div class = "News"> 
              <a href = "#" class = "article-title">Заголовок новости</a>
              <p></p>
  
              
             
              <time class = "time" datetime="21-12-2020 19:21" >Вчера в 19:21</time>
  
              <div class = "article-text">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <a href = "#" class = "read_all">Читать полностью</a>
              </div>
  
             </article>

            </div>


           <article class = "article">

           
            <a href = "#" class = "article-title">Заголовок новости</a>
            <p></p>
            
            <a href = "#" class = "author">L0remio</a>
            <img src = "901430.png" class = "avatar">
            <time class = "time" datetime="21-12-2020 19:21" >Вчера в 19:21</time> 



            <div class = "article-text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                
              </p>
              <a href = "#" class = "read_all" id = "show-moddal">Читать полностью</a>

              <div id = "modal1" class = "modal">

                <div class = "modal_content">

                  <span class = "modal_close">&times;</span>
                  <a href = "#" class = "article-title_modal">Заголовок новости</a>
                  <p></p>
                  <time class = "time" datetime="21-12-2020 19:21" >Вчера в 19:21</time> 
                  <div class = "modal-text">
                    <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

            <h3 class = "content-title2">Видео</h3>

            <div class = "uvideo">
              <iframe class = "uvideo-content" id = "part3" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RkRwLUf8YCQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              <div class = "uvideo-content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
            </div>

            

           </article>

            <div class = "footer">
               <div class = "footer-instagram"></div>
               <div class = "footer-youtube">
                <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjkAxHot0Zs7bhf8XJcrIPA/videos" target = "_blank" class = "yoytube">YouTube</a>
               </div>
               <div class = "footer-sendemail">
                 <a href = "mailto:gohavelik@gmail.com" class = "memeil" id = "part4">gohavelik@gmail.com</a>
               </div>

               <div class = "data_site">
                 Сделано 2021.26.01-05
               </div>

            </div> 
         </main>
            
        </div>
     </div>

    
    <script src = "main.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Буду очень благодарен если вы мне поможете.)

Comment: У вас backgorund добавлен только для class="content". Вот он и добавляется к одному элементу с этим классом.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background: grey;
}
```

Сделает фон для всей страницы

Comment: попробуйте, выйдет не то что надо

Answer (score 0):

Как уже говорил @Lukas,

> У вас backgorund добавлен только для class="content". Вот он и добавляется к одному элементу с этим классом.

Подумав немного, я добавил задний фон классу "page".

```
.page {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 width: 1870px;
 background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
 }
```

Comment: Почему не проголосовали за полезный комментарий?)

Comment: @OleksiiZelenko попросту забыл)